# How do I delete filtered rows in BigTable GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I trying to delete filtered rows in BigTable.

I have a table that has an empty value in a cell that I would like to remove the row from the table,
I wrote a filter that select the relevant rows, but when I try to delete the rows, I get an error. 
    `enter code hereAttributeError: 'PartialRowData' object has no attribute 'delete'`

I would like to know how should I Filter the relevant rows that base on the filter and delete them.

My code wrote in Python

```
col1_filter = row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter(b'customerId')
label1_filter = row_filters.ValueRegexFilter('')
chain1 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(filters=[col1_filter, label1_filter])

partial_rows = table.read_rows(filter_=chain1)

for row in partial_rows:
    row.delete()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get that error because the [PartialRowsData](https://gcloud-python-bigtable.readthedocs.io/en/data-api-complete/row-data.html#gcloud_bigtable.row_data.PartialRowsData) does not have a delete function. You have to create a row from it (eg [DirectRow](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/row.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row.DirectRow)), than you can call the delete function or delete_cell function on it.

Comment: Thank you, do you mean to create the row base the row_key :
        row = table.row(data.row_key)
        row.delete()
        row.commit()

Comment: Yes, that will delete the whole row. If you would like to delete only the `customerId` cell, you can use the delete_cell() function with column family and qualifier parameters.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I added another question about read and modify, I will appreciate if you have exemple https://stackoverflow.com/q/57914718/5082288