# Read And Modify On Same Transaction - Bigtable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am building a coupon system and I am using Bigtable.

My schema has two columns - Customer ID and Coupon code.

I would like to query the table to check if the customer already exists and if it is true, return the code and if it is false, modify the Customer ID cell with the ID and return back the code.

I saw there is an option to do it in Bigtable `ReadModifyWriteRow` operator or with `CheckAndMutateRow` but I have not found any references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has API documentation for Bigtable and Python available [here](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/index.html). This shows you all the available methods and the source code that they refer to, so you can easily and more effectively use and understand the usage.

[`ReadModifyWriteRow`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/bigtable/data-api.html#direct-vs-conditional-vs-append) appends as bytes or increments data in an existing cell in a row.

[`CheckAndMutateRow`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/bigtable/data-api.html#direct-vs-conditional-vs-append) checks if a filter matched and then applies 2 sets of mutations. These are “true mutations” and “false mutations”.

You can use `if` statements in order to achieve the usage that you wish.

You can read about [CheckAndMutateRow conditional requests](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writes#conditional), and there are also [code samples](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data#conditional) available.

Comment: Thank you, maybe you code example how should I implement it ?

Comment: You can view the implementation for `ReadModifyWriteRow` [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/2aae624081f652427052fb652d3ae43d8ac5bf5a/bigtable-protos/src/main/proto/google/bigtable/v1/bigtable_service.proto#L70-L72) and the implementation for `CheckAndMutateRow` [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/2aae624081f652427052fb652d3ae43d8ac5bf5a/bigtable-protos/src/main/proto/google/bigtable/v1/bigtable_service.proto#L62-L64). That will provide insight as to how you can implement these methods within your own implementation. Hope this helps.